# field level permissions in rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple rails application with a Student model. This model has few sensitive fields that should be hidden for some of the users and visible for others.

For example, the TeacherComment should be visible to all teachers where the Grade should be visible to the student and his teacher. on the other hand, the Student Name is available to all users.

As for now, I've implement this requirement at the show.html.erb where I'm verifying the user's type before displaying each one if the sensitive fields.

This approach is error prone and hard to maintain as the application will grow, so I was wondering if there is a better way to handle this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this question is to use a pre-existing gem that implements some form of role-based authorization. That will provide the helpers and model level tools, as well as examples of best practices. You can find a list of such gems here - https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization